# dynamic insert query based on xml tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am novice in Xpath and XSLT.
I want to construct a insert query dynamically based on the element tags in the my XML.

For example I have an xml:

```
<emp>    
    <name>Harry</name>    
    <empcode>IT142</empcode>    
    <dept>IT</dept>    
</emp>
```

So the result should be

```
"insert into emp(name,empcode,dept) values(Harry,IT142,IT);"
```

Comment: Sorry, the xml will look like this <emp><name>Harry</name><empcode>IT142</empcode><dept>IT</dept></emp>

Answer (score 3):

The stylesheet below does not rely on any actual element names, but only on the *position* of elements. Use `xsl:text` to insert the fixed strings and `for-each` to iterate through the child elements of `emp` twice.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>"INSERT INTO </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/>

      <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
              <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>

      <xsl:text> values(</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
              <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>);"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
"INSERT INTO emp(name, empcode, dept) values(Harry, IT142, IT);"
```

I assumed that `""` should be part of the output. Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3o).

Answer (score 0):

Find below xslt for your xml to generate given output.
If you need any change, change according to your requirement.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="//emp">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('insert into emp(name,empcode,dept) values(', name, ',', empcode, ',',dept ,');')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think "name", "empcode" and "dept" are not known in advance and should come from the XML document. Also, you forgot to close the last parenthesis and the `;` - and if you do not specify the method of output, your XSLT processor will very likely add an XML declaration.

Comment: I have updated my xslt to specify output. And you are right, my xslt will not work for unknown xml nodes .